# Tuple manipulation in PySpark with lambda, python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tuples, rdd

I have a parallelized list of tuples in the format:

```
data= [('Emily', (4, 2)),
        ('Alfred', (1, 12)),
        ('George', (10, 2))]
list = sc.parallelize(data)
```

What I want is to multiply the integers within the tuples which will give me this output:

```
[('Emily', (8)),
 ('Alfred', (12)),
 ('George', (20))]
```

I have tried:

```
list = list.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]*x[2]))
```

But with not effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you lambda `x[1]` is a tuple (`(4, 2)`...), so you need to access the first and second values you want to multiply (`x[1][0]`...).

Try this instead:

```
result = list.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0] * x[1][1]))

print(result.collect())
#[('Emily', 8), ('Alfred', 12), ('George', 20)]
```

---

Another way by passing the tuple to reduce function with `mul` operator:

```
import operator
import functools

list.map(lambda x: (x[0], functools.reduce(operator.mul, x[1], 1)))
```